# How to build a dependent project before dockerizing the Main Application using the jar of this dependent project?

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need to dockerize a Spring Boot Microservice project. But we have two utility projects which are used by the services. So is there a way to build these project first so that while dockerizing the services we have the jar available each time before I run the compose ?

PS : I wrote a script which will build these dependent project first but if somebody has a better approach then it can be helpful

Comment: What kind of app are the utility services? Maven?

Comment: Yes it is maven

Comment: Have you considered publishing these libraries? Then you can use them in the microservice's pom file as maven dependency and they will be picked up during docker build.

Comment: Yes these are added as dependencies in the pom file of other microservices. But how do I ensure that the utility jar is always built before the images of microservice is built ? I mean in my local I can make the jar by running "mvn install"

Comment: If you have published utility artifacts on a maven repo, they will be always available during build of the micro service. In case that publishing is not an option take a look on multistage builds.